# javascript once script is parsed are the variables initialized as well?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a script file that takes 10 seconds to parse. The file is mainly made of code like ... `var x = Backbone.model.extend({})` and some like `var y = x.extend({}).`

What I'm wondering is that on Chrome's dev timeline the parsing of the file shows as 10 seconds, so during parsing did the _.extend of underscore execute to create the constructors i.e. `x,y` etc?

Comment: Parsing alone shouldn't execute the script IMO. It's when you create the script element (which should also Parse/compile/initialize) when it's executed and it's only after the script is being executed that those variables are available.

Comment: You're script should not be taking 10s to parse, something is wrong

Comment: Your wondering many things... what exactly is the question..?

Comment: the question is about what happens when the javascript file is parsed. Does is simple register the statements or evaluate expressions as well?
Well by wrapping the variable declarations like var x = function(){
return Backbone.View.extend(..
} The script evaluation time on the chrome dev tool timeline now comes up as 1.8 seconds.. 

But if the for loops running inside the _.extend method was taking all that time then I wonder why it did not show in the dev tools timeline under the evaluate script as children.